# Not able to run A-frame scenes in oculus quest 2

Tags: aframe

I ran the A-frame scene in my desktop and it worked fine but on Oculus quest 2 I am unable to move.

Comment: You mean it freezes after entering VR mode?

Comment: Can share a link with an example to reproduce? Sharing simple code with glitch highly recommended https://glitch.com/~aframe